# Unresolved Reference: Re.Compile as a parameter in Python

Tags: python, function, reference, beautifulsoup

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


r1 = requests.get(firsturl)
soup1 = BeautifulSoup(r1.content, "lxml")
table = soup1.select('div#my-players-table table')[0]
row = table.find('td', align='left', text = re.compile('Patriots'))
for cell in row.find_next_siblings('td'):
print(cell.text)
```

The error occurs in the row = table.find, it says that `text = re.compile` cannot work because `re` is an unresolved reference.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you `import`ed `re` in your code ?

Comment: did you `import re` library?